# Firebase dynamic links - bulk list

Tags: firebase, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

In my application i'm running a cronjob daily in order to get a list of items from a set of providers.

Each item has an image, a title, and a url.

I want to create a Firebase dynamic link out of these parameters and then shorten it.

From the docs of Firebase i saw that it's possible to create the dynamic link offline, and then get the shorten version through a REST API(https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest).

From what i see i have to send one request for each item. I was wondering if there is a way to get the shorten urls out of a list of items with a single request.

In alternative, other url shortener service suggested for this use case?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?